# How to call a function in PHP file in another folder by a controller in custom module?

Tags: magento-1.9, admin-controller

I need to call PHP function within my custom module controller. But the relevant PHP file contain in different folder. How I solve this? `

```
<?php function doLog($text) { 
// open log file
$filename = "form_ipn.log";
$fh = fopen($filename, "a") or die("Could not open log file.");
fwrite($fh, date("d-m-Y, H:i")." - $text\n") or die("Could not write
file!");
fclose($fh);
}
doLog("This is test");
?>
```

Comment: Can you please be more specific? Is the code in a PHP class? What kindof classis? Model or Helper?

Comment: @RiccardoT No this is just a PHP file that containing function to write/append log file. Path for the file magento->testing->test.php. I have updated my question with code.

Comment: Why on earth are you doing this in the first place? Use the logging functionality provided in magento framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mention URL like `$url = 'http://127.0.0.1/magento/testing/curl.php';`
or you should get base directory like `$media_path = Mage::getBaseDir('media');` or you can redirect to relevant URL.